# What is the date and time in USA for performing amavasya corresponding to IST 9 AM on 20th February, 2023

Tags: krishna, yajur-veda

What is the date and time in the USA  for performing Amavasya corresponding to IST 9 AM on 20th February 2023 Also Sangalpam is to be made in the USA on That date

Comment: Check on Drikpanchang.com .. set your city and they will show you the correct timings for any given festivals/occasions.

Comment: This can easily be searched up online in a timezone converter. It is not useful nor efficient to ask a question of this sort here.

Answer (score 1):

the timing to perform amavasya corresponding to IST 9 AM on the 20th of February, will be at 7:30 PM Feb 19 (PST). I hope that answered your question.